# Put text from array list to separate lines

Tags: java, html, string, swing, label

I have `ArrayList` where I put Author, Title and Value(integer). I want to put them in label and print in separate lines. But what I get is that text is printed in one line.

```
for (Book book : listofbooks) {
    labelis.setText(labelis.getText() + "\nName: " + book.getName() + "Tile: " + book.getTitle() + "Number of books: " + book.getHowMany());
}
panel.add(labelis);
```

Why `\n` does not work?

**EDIT**: Solution:

```
for (Book book : listofbooks) {

        label.setText( "<html> "
        + label.getText() 
        + "<br>Name: " + book.getName()
        + "Tile: " + book.getTitle()
        + "Number of books: " 
        + book.getHowMany()
        );

    }
    label.setText(label.getText()+ "</html>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML tags in your JLabel. Try to seperate your Strings with that break tag: `<br>`

```
    label.setText("<html> +"
            + label.getText() 
            + "<br>Name: " + book.getName()
            + "Tile: " + book.getTitle()
            + "Number of books: " 
            + book.getHowMany()
            + "</html>");
```

**NOTE**: Your JLabel text has to start with the opening `<html>` and end with the closing `</html>`.

Comment: it doesn't work. `<br>` don't creat a new line, but  text "<br>" is added to the label.

Comment: does your Label start with `<html>`? I edited my post. Check it out.

Comment: Now only first line is printed (I have three `ArrayList` elements)